# How to set the MediaBox values with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to change the mediabox entries of each page of my pdf.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg6zL.png[image]

Is there a way to do that with iText so that the following values will be used

```
mediaBox[0] = 0
mediaBox[1] = 0
mediaBox[2] = 595.22
mediaBox[0] = 842
```

Comment: iText 5 or iText 7? Are you creating a document from scratch, or do you want to change the MediaBox in an existing document? (Note that the existing content doesn't reflow if you change the MediaBox of an existing document. If you aren't careful, you can easily clip existing content.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could solve this by setting the mediaboxes like this

```
 File outputPdf = File.createTempFile("moveMediabox", ".pdf");
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ByteSource.wrap(inputPdfBytes).openBufferedStream());
 PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outputPdf));
 int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();

 for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
        PdfDictionary pagedict = reader.getPageN(i);
        PdfArray mediabox = pagedict.getAsArray(PdfName.MEDIABOX);
        int x = mediabox.getAsNumber(0).intValue();
        int y = mediabox.getAsNumber(1).intValue();
        if (x != 0 && y != 0){
            isChanged = true;
            mediabox.set(0, new PdfNumber(0));
            mediabox.set(1, new PdfNumber(0));
            mediabox.set(2, new PdfNumber(mediabox.getAsNumber(2).intValue() - x));
            mediabox.set(3, new PdfNumber(mediabox.getAsNumber(3).intValue() - y)); 
        }
        else{
            LOG.info("no need to repair media box, already at x:0 y:0");
        }
    }
```